# How to use single watch on multiple Model values

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 5 v-Models. I am using 5 Watch statements to trigger one function on change of any v-model. How can I combine all v-models under single watch statement.

Comment: is it same function and v-model for different different pages? then use mixn to resolve this issue

Comment: all things are in same component.

Comment: could you please show the code

Comment: All below Models on which Watch is executed are in same component template:
  @Watch('fromTime')
  updateFromTime(){
    console.log('time changed ---> ');
  }
  
  @Watch('fromTimeWindow')
  updateFromTimeWindow(){
    console.log('time changed ---> ');
  }


  @Watch('toTime')
    updateToTime(){
      console.log('time changed ---> ');
    }

  @Watch('toTimeWindow')
  updateToTimeWindow(){
    console.log('time changed ---> ');
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try watching an array:

```js
this.$watch(() => [this.a, this.b, this.c], () => {
  console.log('a, b or c changed')
})
```

Comment: in typescript it complains when I provide array in Watch instead string.

Comment: The first argument is a function, not an array.